# Trying to set up RBENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rbenv

I have been following this guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx0NrIbQbzI

However I do not have a clue what he does at 2:02?

I type what he typed but mine looks different, I get:

```
# added by Anaconda 2.1.0 installer   
export PATH="/Users/me/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
-- INSERT --
```

and try and paste what he pasted at the top (above # which lets me, but then he does something and enters :wq and then goes back to the Terminal which I cannot seem to do?

Comment: Press ESC, if you are not familiar with vim, just use any text editors you like.

Comment: I pressed ESC it doesn't do anything?